# build constraints exclude all Go files in

Tags: go, go-modules

When I import "golang.org/x/net/route"

It tells me:
"build constraints exclude all Go files in go/src/golang.org/x/net/routego"

I am using VSCode on Windows/Linux.

I searched online and didn't see a solution to a similar problem.

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/net/route"
)

{
    rib, _ := route.FetchRIB(0, route.RIBTypeRoute, 0)
    messages, err := route.ParseRIB(route.RIBTypeRoute, rib)
}
```

Comment: what fixed my issue was adding a main.go file (for some reason it was missing from my project dir)

Answer (score 53):

I had this problem in *Goland* (with source code on WSL2 and Goland on win).

I was able to solve it with

```
go clean -modcache
```

Subsequent build put everything in order again.

Comment: This solved my problem. And I understand that go does intelligence around what files to build, if you set the `GO_OS` or name a file like `xyz_<OS>.go`, which can lead to the unfortunate fact of having 0 files to build with even though there are source files in the pwd... However, I'm not sure what happened such that removing cached modules fixes this? What happened?

Comment: I'm rather new to Go, so I drew from my "general experience" and speculated, after some reading here, that the cache was "mixed up". Meaning, I was installing packages using Golang AND the console. If there is some configuration going on--as you mentioned--the cache would "contradict" itself. Once again, just a thought! And I'd be very happy to amend my answer with a proper explanation, if we find something reproducible.

Comment: This got me mostly there. Running `go mod tidy` completed the task.

Answer (score 17):

My issue was that I had a stray `import "C"` in my code and I was compiling with `CGO_ENABLED=0`. This problem was hard to find because IntelliJ collapses all the imports into one statement.

Comment: temporary enable cgo with: **env CGO_ENABLED=1 go run main**

Comment: Also I needed to set `CC=<path to gcc>`

Answer (score 11):

We met the same error under `Goland`, and it could be solved in [this way](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/configuring-build-constraints-and-vendoring.html#build-constraints)

If you want to set `GOOS = linux` under Mac, just add this line in the header of file `// +build linux,amd64,go1.15,!cgo` which means we declare that this file is for the target system that has the following requirements: Linux, the AMD64 architecture, the 1.15 Go version, and no CGO support.

---

**Update 08/04/2022**

After [go 1.17](https://go.dev/doc/go1.17#go-command). The go command now understands `//go:build` lines and prefers them over `// +build` lines. The new syntax uses boolean expressions, just like Go, and should be less error-prone. Here are some more [details](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-gobuild.md)

```
// go:build (darwin && cgo) || linux
// +build darwin,cgo linux
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a dependency requiring cgo (which includes x/net by default), you will get this error if your system does not have a C compiler. Can be easily fixed by installing gcc.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it turned out to be for me. I was working in a new codebase (and I'm new to Go) and didn't have GCC on my box. I installed GCC and it built. The error message is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

try to remove folder x in go/src/golang.org/

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue by simply doing Invalidate Caches under File Tab.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just by an accident replaced original code by test file, it was containing the following comments:

```
//go:build unittest
// +build unittest
```

Comment: upvoted!  This seems like it would be a commonly overlooked issue.  I had the inversion of this issue.  I.E. my test file didn't have the build constraints indicating this is a test file - so my test file wasn't allowed to import our core test files.  The complication in my case was my test file was importing a package which requires cgo to be enabled - so I wasted a bunch of time ensuring that cgo had all necessary prequisites enabled.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, after trying the `go clean -modcache` solution, I also had to restart Goland before it stopped complaining about the build constraints.

Comment: For me restarting IntelliJ worked. Thanks Martin!!

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to present itself rather ambiguously.

In my case, my project uses CGO, and this error manifests when `CGO_ENABLED=0` in the environment, which is solved by unsetting this env var, or setting `CGO_ENABLED=1`

Answer (score 1):

In my case it appears the go get failed and the folder referenced in GOPATH was empty. Check your library folder which is complaining here. [image: here]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to import "golang.org/x/sync".  I did not realise that (unlike the Go library "sync" package) there are only sub-packages in x/sync.

I should have been importing "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup".

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was building a docker image.
Changing from alpine `FROM golang:1.22-alpine` to `FROM golang:1.22` helps.

Was not a problem for me, because I was using multistage-builds anyways.

Answer (score -1):

"build constraints exclude all Go files in go/src/golang.org/x/net/routego"
In Intellij :

1. Navigate to the folder in the project explorer
2. Right click -> Mark folder as not excluded.

Answer (score -2):

If you get error `build constraints exclude all Go files in ...` with `go get` command, please specify the path as follows

Error:

```
$ go get {HOST}/platform/be-photo
```

Success:

```
$ go get {HOST}/platform/be-photo/external/client
```