# How to build Go Executables for windows from Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: go, apple-m1

I have a new MacBook with an m1 chip.

I want to make an windows executable file from a main.go file. Internally it uses couple of external libraries. I am able to build executable for m1 processor using the command `go build main.go`.

But when I try to build windows executable using command `env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build main.go`, it fails with `build constraints exclude all Go files`

```
dilipyadav@Dilips-MacBook-Pro-2 isengard % pwd
/Users/dilipyadav/githome/my-project/cmd/isengard
dilipyadav@Dilips-MacBook-Pro-2 isengard % ls
main.go
dilipyadav@Dilips-MacBook-Pro-2 isengard % env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build main.go
package command-line-arguments
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/app
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/painter/gl
    imports github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl: build constraints exclude all Go files in /Users/dilipyadav/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/gl@v0.0.0-20190320180904-bf2b1f2f34d7/v3.2-core/gl
package command-line-arguments
    imports github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio: build constraints exclude all Go files in /Users/dilipyadav/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio@v0.0.0-20200911161147-bb74aa485641
dilipyadav@Dilips-MacBook-Pro-2 isengard %
```

I am following the build document from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-go-executables-for-multiple-platforms-on-ubuntu-16-04)

For the error `build constraints exclude all Go files`, I checked [build constraints exclude all Go files in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348458/build-constraints-exclude-all-go-files-in).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

run this inside your project main folder (where main.go exists)

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o output_name.exe
```

Comment: `dilipyadav@Dilips-MacBook-Pro-2 my-project % GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o output_name.exe`
    `no Go files in /Users/dilipyadav/githome/my-project`

Comment: I have the main.go file inside my-project/cmd/isengard folder. Root folder has only go.mod.

Comment: run inside the folder where main.go file exists

Comment: I did. I got `package github.com/conversenow/my-project/cmd/isengard: build constraints exclude all Go files in /Users/dilipyadav/githome/my-project/cmd/isengard`

Comment: can you run and build in your OS?

Comment: Yes, I am able to run and build on my OS.