# Build constraints exclude all the Go files in '/home/masoud/go/src/gorm.io/gorm' Ubuntu

Tags: linux, go, goland

I get this error, while I import gorm package into my project.
I am using Goland on Ubuntu 22.

```
Build constraints exclude all the Go files in '/home/masoud/go/src/gorm.io/gorm'
```

Comment: that would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/67020638

Comment: You can set corresponding build tags in the settings: _File | Settings | Go | Build Tags & Vendoring_.

Comment: @s0xzwasd
it does not work for me

Comment: What version of GoLand are you using?

Comment: @s0xzwasd
Goland Version : 2022.2.4 |
Go Version : 1.18.7 linux/amd64

Comment: Can you share a sample project to reproduce it?

Comment: Thank you @s0xzwasd for your reply; it has been fixed by deleting the project and cloning it from git.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue for me was as simple as using

`go clean -modcache`

and then following that with

`go mod tidy`

Comment: Thanks
It did not work for me in this case, any other ideas?

Comment: @MasoudHosseini Not too sure honestly. try what they say in this post maybe. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4407257418514-Build-constraints-exclude-all-the-Go-files-in-

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed!
I deleted the project and its directory, and I cloned it again from git.
After that I ran:
`go mod tidy`
and boom, I can develop smoothly.