# Build Constraints restricting fyne import for VS Code on Windows

Tags: go, import, constraints, fyne

I have imported the fyne GUI , and now my  GoLang compiler that there is an error imported the files because the build constraints.

I have tried cleaning out caches using commands from this post, which asks about VS Code in Windows, the same IDE and OS I am using:

[build constraints exclude all Go files in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348458/build-constraints-exclude-all-go-files-in)

I made sure I had Gcc C compiler downloaded, which may have contributed to my problem.

I still got the following errors in my source code (with respective import statements)

// RecursivePlant.go
package main
// create Gui's
import (

```
// "fmt"
"image"
"image/color"
"image/draw"
"image/png"
"math"
"os"
"time"

"fyne.io/fyne/v2"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
```

)

"error while importing fyne.io/fyne/v2/app: build constraints exclude all Go files in C:\Users\geniu\go\pkg\mod\github.com\go-gl\gl@v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6\v3.2-core\gl"

// RecursiveNoise.go
package main

import (
"image"
"image/color"
"image/draw"
"image/png"
"math/rand"
"os"
"time"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

"error while importing fyne.io/fyne/v2/app: build constraints exclude all Go files in C:\Users\geniu\go\pkg\mod\github.com\go-gl\gl@v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6\v3.2-core\gl"

and the go.mod file:

module example.com/hello
go 1.20
require fyne.io/fyne/v2 v2.3.5

with error message:

"error while importing fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/painter/gl: build constraints exclude all Go files in C:\Users\geniu\go\pkg\mod\github.com\go-gl\gl@v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6\v3.2-core\gl"

I have been studying up on build constraints but I am unclear on which constraint to use (based on operating system, compiler, development stage etc) and which files to but the build constraints in. I don't know which part of my go or fyne files have this problem.

Comment: Can you run `gcc` command on your cmd and say the output ?

Comment: COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
...Build-2'
Thread model: win32
gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-2)

Comment: I had to abridge it a little bit

Comment: It looks like your gcc set up properly. Can you try this on your VScode terminal `CGO_ENABLED=1 go run main.go` replace `main.go` with your file name which one has main function then say the output if any.

Comment: Here is the output: PS C:\Users\geniu> CGO_ENABLED=1 go run RecursivePlant.go
CGO_ENABLED=1 : The term 'CGO_ENABLED=1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ CGO_ENABLED=1 go run RecursivePlant.go
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CGO_ENABLED=1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: The "build contraints" import errors are still there.    Here is the result of putting it in the terminal.  I did not put the instruction in the directory of my source code file.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem between gcc and VScode. I am not using Windows hence I can't say definite things. In my linux OS when I removed gcc and run an example code from fyne library, I got same error. You need run `CGO_ENABLED=1 go run main.go` from the directory where your file (which one has main function)  located.      Can you try it on the cmd ? not in the VScode.  But before run that code please change the current directory to the directory which your file (which one has main function) including.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254128/discussion-between-t-j-foster-and-brokenarmor).

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to “use” any constraints, it is all automatic
Probably VSCode cannot find your C compiler. Typically this is because it is set up only on a different terminal (MSYS2 for example only configures it’s own window.

First try compiling from the place you set up the C compiler. Get that working (following our docs perhaps) then at leas you know the tools are all installed. https://developer.fyne.io/started/

Comment: Where would "the place I set up the compiler" be.  In my program files?   I'm not sure exactly which file I need to put my source code into.  Do I put it in the same directory as MinGW?  MSYS2?

Comment: Nothing needs to be in the same folder… you just need to use the terminal in the setup docs to know if it’s working (follow the steps carefully).

Comment: Once working you should just need to copy the environment variables over to your preferred console. Our docs don’t cover specifics for every configuration on Windows as sadly the OS can be a bit of a mess for development.